# Dev Express inject properties into edit form

Tags: devexpress-mvc

I use the Dev Express MVC Gridview's default ability to auto-generate the edit form for editing fields, using the grid column properties.  The edit form shows as a popup when "Edit" is clicked, as per the CommandColumn default.  However, I'm trying to inject some property values at the time the popup opens.  For performance reasons, I can't set these properties on the core grid data.

Is there some event I can access that will allow me to set control values when the popup is rendering?  My intention is probably to get these values via Ajax and set them, unless there is simpler way to get this data from the server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem using assistance from Dev Express support.  You can see the solution here:
https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/T161034